# SQL query for conditional select

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have tables like this:

Table: Factors

```
FactorID   SellerID   ContractorID
---------------------------------
1            -1          2
2             1         -1
3            -1          1
4             2         -1
```

Table: Sellers

```
SellerID   SellerName
---------------------
1            SellerA      
2            SellerB      
3            SellerC      
4            SellerD
```

Table Contractors:

```
ContractorID   ContractorName
-------------------------------
1                    W      
2                    X      
3                    Y      
4                    Z
```

i want to have query that return some like this:

```
FactorID   SellerID   ContractorID   ContractorName     SellerName
------------------------------------------------------------------
1            -1          2                  X                NULL
2             1         -1                  NULL             SellerA
3            -1          1                  W                NULL   
4             2         -1                  NULL             SellerB
```

this is my query but not worked correctly:

```
SELECT  Factos.* ,
        Seller.sellerName AS sellerName ,
        Contractor.Contractor AS contractorName
FROM    Fctors ,
        Seller ,
        Contractor
WHERE   Seller.SellerID = CASE WHEN Factors.ContrarID = -1 THEN Factors.SellerID
                               ELSE ''
                          END
        AND Contractor.ContractorID = CASE WHEN Factors.SellerID = -1 THEN Factors.ContractorID
                                           ELSE ''
                                      END
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? you are selecting `from Fctors` instead of `from Factors` - is that how you do it in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `CASE`. [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) should be enough.
That should do:

```
  SELECT f.FactorID,
         f.SellerID,
         f.ContractorID,
         c.ContractorName,
         s.SellerName
    FROM Factors f
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Sellers s 
                         ON f.SellerID = s.SellerID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Contractor c
                         ON f.SellerID = c.SellerID
ORDER BY f.FactorID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple JOIN statement should provide required result without any CASE statements

```
SELECT f.*, s.sellerName as sellerName, c.Contractor as contractorName
  FROM Factors f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sellers s ON(f.SellerId=s.SellerId)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Contractors c ON(f.ContractorId=c.ContractorId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT a.*, b.SellerName, c.ContractorName
FROM
Factors A LEFT JOIN Sellers b on a.SellerID=b.SellerID
    LEFT JOIN Contractors c on a.ContractorID=c.ContractorID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get that result just using a query, check below query

```
SELECT F.FactorID, S.SellerID, C.ContractorID, C.ContractorName, S.SellerName FROM FACTORS F LEFT JOIN SELLERS S ON F.SellerID = S.SellerID
          LEFT JOIN CONTRACTORS C ON F.ContractorID = C.ContractorID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Factors.FactorID,Sellers.SellerID AS SellerID ,
Contractors.ContractorID AS ContractorID,
Contractors.ContractorName AS ContractorName,
Sellers.SellerName AS SellerName

FROM Factors LEFT JOIN Sellers ON Factors.FactorID=Sellers.SellerID
LEFT JOIN Contractors ON Factors.FactorID=Contractors.ContractorID
```

Answer (score 1):

`Left Outer join` is all you need

```
select f.FactorID, f.SellerID, f.ContractorID, c.ContractorName, s.SellerName
from Factors f left outer join Sellers s on f.SellerID = s.SellerID
    left outer join Contractors c on f.ContractorID = c.ContractorID
```